# angular search filter with boolean checkboxes

Tags: angular, pipe, angular-filters, angular-pipe

I'm new in Angular, I have a list of components that I want to filter according to some check boxes, using pipes and I don't know how to achieve this.

So far I have an interface

```
export interface Parking {
    multiple: boolean;
    public: boolean;
    name: string;
}
```

the pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: unknown, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
    
    return null;
 
  }

}
```

Search component

```
<form>
  
    <div class="form-group mt-2">
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1" >Public</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2" >Private</label>
        </div>
    
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1" >Single</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1" >Multiple</label>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</form>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})

export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

and in the template for displaying components (map.component.html)

```
<div *ngFor="let parking of (parkings | filter)">
{{parking.name}}
</div>
```

I don't know how to continue for filtering according to checkboxes when checked

Thank you!

Comment: what is single/Multiple? how are they put into account in filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an object that contains all your filter options and initialize them as **false**.

```
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public filters = {
    public: false,
    private: false,
    single: false,
    multiple: false,
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Now bind them in your template like this

```
<form>
  
    <div class="form-group mt-2">
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="filter.public">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1" >Public</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="filter.private">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2" >Private</label>
        </div>
    
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="filter.single">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1" >Single</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="filter.multiple">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1" >Multiple</label>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</form>
```

So whenever any of these is checked it's value will be **true.**
Now, pass this *filters* object to your pipe: `parkings | filter : filters`

```
<div *ngFor="let parking of (parkings | filter : filters)">
  {{parking.name}}
</div>
```

and get them in your filter

```
transform(values: Parking[], filters:any): Parking[]{
  
  // In case this is not getting any filters object, just return the same array
  if(!filters)
    return values;


  /*** If actually got filters, just use the filter() method that arrays have ***/

  // If you checked the "public" checkbox this if() statement will be solved to true
  // so executates this filtering
  if(filters.public){
    // This is gonna filter array and return only current items where public is true
    values = values.filter(item => item.public); // item => item.public == true
  }

  if(filters.multiple){
    // This is gonna filter the filtered array again, so if you already
    // excluded the private ones (so if parking.public is false),
    // now based on that results you will keep 
    values = values.filter(item => item.multiple);
  }

  return values;

}
```

This way you can continue filtering. I'm executing each filter manually in case you'd like to add different conditions and so, but let's imagine you have a list of 10 filters where the condition will be always the same: `values = values.filter(item => item.something == true);` you could simplify this by looping the *filters object* with **Object.keys()** wich returns an array of keys from the object. Just like this:

```
transform(values: Parking[], filters:any): Parking[]{
  
  if(!filters)
    return values;

  Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => {
    if(filters[key]){
      values = values.filter(item => item[key]);
    }
  })

  return values;

}
```

Note: this last method applies if your Parking properties are the same that the `filters` ones.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I followed your guidelines, thank you but I don't know how to trigger pipe when the filter changes

Comment: I marked pipe as impure (it is a good solution, there is another solution ?) and now it's triggered but I get undefined for filter in transform method, how can I get the filter ? Thank you

Comment: Make sure you're passing your filters object (assuming you followed the first step, now you have all your filters into this.filters). Just realized I had a mistake in my answer but just make sure in your html you're applying your pipe like this: `parkings | filter : filters`

Hope it solves it. 
You're welcome. ;)

Comment: Hi Daniel, it works now but I had to get filter parameter from parent component (map.component) with **@ViewChild(FilterComponent)  filters** because filter.component is a child of map.component, now it arrives in pipe component. Thank you !